# Serial port sniffer / monitor / logger software for Windows 7, 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, usb, 64-bit, serial-port, sniffing

*Question edited.*

Need to understand the serial communication protocol between a USB device and PC, that uses serial over USB communication. I was planning on using a software based approach for serial port sniffing / monitoring / logging the serial communication.

My constraint is availability of PCs running Windows 7 64-bit only, and none of the methods I have come across work on this setup. Here are some that I've tried:

- [How can I monitor a virtual serial port in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/343942/how-can-i-monitor-a-virtual-serial-port-in-windows-7)
- [I'm looking for serial port monitoring software](https://superuser.com/questions/242997/im-looking-for-serial-port-monitoring-software)
- [RS232 Packet Sniffer](https://superuser.com/questions/101775/rs232-packet-sniffer)
- [Is there a free way to monitor a serial port on Windows 7 x64?](https://superuser.com/questions/431660/is-there-a-free-way-to-monitor-a-serial-port-on-windows-7-x64)

Looking for alternative ideas, approaches ? Hardware based approach would not be my first choice, but anything that can be done at a low-cost, or better still -- DIY, I'd love to hear more.

Comment: Do you want to use a Hardware logger?

Comment: @moses, done. Hopefully it is no longer a product recommendation query. OTOH, I hope an answer can be valid with a product recommendation, as a solution.

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri, if those are the only working alternatives, then I could go for hardware logger. Hardware loggers for USB-based devices (even though they use serial over USB), I think - are both complex and expensive, no ? Anyhow, open to suggestions.

Comment: @icarus74 i know several open sources with different capabilities and for different tasks. You need serial port sniffing/monitoring soft for individual tasks or for enterprise ?

Comment: @Ice, for individual task back then. Although I am no longer working on the project, it'd still be good to know what the options are.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the best way to understand the serial communication is with special software( as you were planning). You need to sniff and monitor serial port ? And with windows 7 x64 support.

Then try this soft - Eltima Serial Port Monitor:
http://www.eltima.com/products/serial-port-monitor/

It can analyze and monitor all serial port activity in a system. Besides, with serial port sniffing.

Comment: You forget to add : App is not free. But with free trial.